# How to automate the steps in the Installshield Wizard?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-installer, installer, installshield

I was working on a project where I need to take latest builds(packaged as installers) and run it in the machine in order to test it. I wanted to just automate that installshield wizard (viz. next->next->next->Agree->Insall->Exit)

Can anybody please tell me if there is some tool/way to do it ?

P.S. : I dont want to take the build from the repository and deploy it. I want to do it via installer only.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [*excellent* unattended sourceforge page](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) in *many* but not *all* cases, all you need to do is run the installer with a /r flag. This generates a unattended.iss file in c:/windows which you can copy out to the same folder. You can then run it with /s to use the script file to pick up on your choices.